# How to resolve the Py4j JavaError while try to write a PySpark DataFrame to CSV file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

`fifa_df.write.mode("overwrite").csv("C:\\Users\\003608\\Desktop\\pyspark_info\\csv_files")`
or
`fifa_df.write.mode("overwrite").csv("C:\\Users\\003608\\Desktop\\pyspark_info\\csv_test.csv")`

Tried both

Error that I got:

`Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)`

Comment: You seem to have not posted the traceback

Comment: Try to describe your question clearer. What are you trying to do and where do you run stuck

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post more of the error message, but try this for now:

```
fifa_df.coalesce(1)\
    .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .option("header", "true")\
  .save("C:\Users\003608\Desktop\pyspark_info\csv_test.csv")
```